# WEGA operating system origins

Tags: history, unix

I just recently stumbled across information about DDR minicomputer [P8000](http://www.pofo.de/P8000/)  and its unixoid operating system WEGA. The website above as well as Wikipedia seem to claim some compatibility or even derivation from western commercial Unix systems.

Since the computer was built in DDR ie behind the iron curtain, how much of the operating system was genuinely implemented there and how much of it was simply copied with or without permission?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

AFAIK it was a complete source level reimplementation of AT&T's System III. Looking at the [source code reconstruction pages](https://github.com/OlliL/P8000/tree/master/WEGA/src), it looks as if the basic structure is quite literal. There are slight differences in variable names and alike - and more so all comments are in German :))

There have been several unix(oide) implementations like V7 based ones in the early 80s on DEC clones as well as /370 mainframes. Plus there has been a System V alike called [MUTOS](http://robotrontechnik.de/index.htm?/html/software/mutos.htm) abailable for U830 (Bitslice), 8086 and Z8001 and K1840 (a VAX Clone)

Here's a nice article about [Unix development in Eastern Germany](https://www.golem.de/news/computergeschichte-unix-hinter-dem-eisernen-vorhang-1905-141247.html) (German).

Comment: The compiler is not present at that github. It's possible they just used the same one from V7, just with a custom backend. Any idea where that might be?